# Can't connect Redux to a grandchild component

Tags: reactjs, redux

How can I connect Redux to a child component that's several layers below the parent component? I can't figure out how to pass `store` into props without it blowing up.

I'm not using IronRouter and am using Redux 3 with React 0.13. Here's an example:

```
const SearchBar = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <div> {this.props.text} </div>;
  }
});


function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {text: state.search.text};
}

_SearchBar = connect(mapStateToProps)(SearchBar);
```

> Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(SearchBar)". Either wrap the root component in a `<Provider>`, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(SearchBar)".

Answer (score 4):

You either need to pass the store all the way down through the intermediary components, or like the message says, utilize the `<Provider>` component at the top of the app which will pass it down automatically.

Comment: Hmm interesting. I tried using `<Provider>` in the 'layout' component and it was always complaining about `store` not being found, even though it was defined. I try that again.  How could I pass "store" as a prop to connect directly?

Comment: @SkinnyG33k You wouldn't pass it to `connect`, you'd pass it as a prop to the component that you render (the return value of `connect`). Using `<Provider>` is really quite a bit better; see https://github.com/rackt/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#remarks

Answer (score 2):

1) Wrap your root component in `<Provider store={store}></Provider>`:

```
class Root extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <YourAppComponent />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

`Provider` passes the store through React's [context](https://www.tildedave.com/2014/11/15/introduction-to-contexts-in-react-js.html).

2) Your `connect()` should work now :), but only if all your connected components are descendants of `<YourAppComponent />`